# How to properly replace a character in a string using java regex?

Tags: java, regex

I my java app, I have a following character sequence:  `b"2` (any single character, followed by a double quote followed by a single-digit number)

I need to replace the double quote with a single quote character.
I'm trying this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".\"d");
Matcher m = p.matcher(initialOutput);
String replacement = m.replaceAll(".'d");
```

This does not seem to do anything.

What is the right way of doing this?

Comment: Check [this](http://rextester.com/XOWAT73699)

Comment: If by *any single character* you mean any *letter*, then the accepted answer is not correct since `.` matches any char, not a letter. Please clarify if you need more help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `d` represents a literal character. You're looking for `\d`, which represents a numeric digit.

The other issue is that you're replacing variable characters with the string literal `".'d"`. One solution is to [*capture*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) the variable portions and reference them in the replacement:

```
String replacement = initialOutput.replaceAll("(.)\"(\\d)", "$1'$2");
```

Another approach is to use [*lookarounds*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check the surrounding characters without actually matching them for replacement:

```
String replacement = initialOutput.replaceAll("(?<=.)\"(?=\\d)", "'");
```